# clarify init method using subclass

Tags: objective-c, initialization, subclass, init

Now i have had this problem clouding my mind for quite sometime and i really need someone to clarify this for me.

1) what is a unique identifier that causes the init method to return a different object other than the one you were initially trying to allocate with the call? 
.. What should you do in such a case?

2) When a designated initializer from one class assuming that class has more than one method, invokes the designated initializer in its parent class consequently invoking NSObject's init method; what exactly is happening when the parent class init method is invoked? what is "self" in that method explicitly referencing to, as well as the "self" returned from its root class?

Comment: I know all these questions are kind of related, but it might be smarter to ask them as five different questions (maybe in sequence, or one day after another, linking back to each).  That way you can get more concise, less rambling answers, and you can probably earn more reputation points (for asking focused questions) in the process.

Comment: lol, for some reason i had the thought about it too, but just dismissed it as i would much rather have it all in one place but thanks, will change that up right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will answer your questions:

- An `init` method is just a method like any other, there is nothing special about them *per se*;
- Method parameters are local variables which are assigned an initial value, that value being the one given in the call;
- `self` is a hidden method parameter, a value for it is passed in the call as with all other parameters;
- The result of the method is implicitly marked with the [`ns_returns_retained` attribute](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values); and finally
- The `self` parameter is implicitly marked with the [`ns_consumed` attribute](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#consumed-parameters).

The attributes mentioned effect how ARC manages the references returned (`ns_returns_retained`) by, or passed to (`ns_consumes`), a method. These attributes can be *explicitly* applied to *any* method.

The attribute `ns_returns_retained` is applied *implicitly* to methods in the `alloc`, `copy`, `init`, `mutableCopy`, and `new` families; while `ns_consumes` is *implicitly* applied to the hidden `self` parameter of `init` methods.

The `ns_consumes` attribute is the only "unusual" feature of `init` methods. It tells ARC that the method being called takes ownership of the passed object reference, and hence is responsible for releasing it when required. So in the common statement found in `init` methods, a call to the superclass `init` method:

```
self = [super init];
```

the current reference stored in `self` is passed to the called method *along with* the callers ownership of that reference. When the result of the call is assigned back to `self` ARC does not need to relinquish ownership (aka "release") the old reference stored there - ownership was already passed to the called method - or take ownership (aka "retain") of the new reference - as the called transfers its ownership back to the caller.

The above allows an `init` method to return a *different* reference than the one it was passed, and releasing the one it was passed. This feature is not commonly used in user classes but a number of common system classes, e.g. `NSString` and `NSNumber`, take advantage to reduce the number of objects needed.

The above sounds more complicated than it is! If you have specific questions then ask new specific questions as @MichaelDautermann suggests in the comments.

HTH

**Addendum**

In response to comments maybe the following will help. *All code typed directly on an iPad, expect errors!*

How does the following method work?

```
- (NSString *) doSomething:(NSString *)aLocal
{
   aLocal = [super aLocal];
   return aLocal;
}
```

In the call:

```
NSString *someResult = [someObjectRef doSomething:someLocalVariable];
```

where `someObjectRef` is a variable holding a reference to an object that declares the above method, and `someLocalVariable` holds a reference to a string.

In outline it is:

- a new method invocation is created along with its local variable `aLocal`
- the reference stored in the callers `someLocalVariable` is copied (it's *value* not the object it references) and stored in `aLocal`
- the statements of the method are executed
- the first statement is a call to the same method implemented in the super class, the value of the reference in `aLocal` is passed to this method, and the reference returned by the call is stored into `aLocal` - replacing the reference previously stored there.
- the second statement returns the value of the reference stored in `aLocal` as the method result, and that reference is stored into the caller's `someLocalVariable`.

None of that should be surprising, and the reference return is probably not the reference passed in (it *could* be, we've no idea what the inherited `doSomething` method does, it may just return what it was passed).

Now all you have to understand is that `self` is an *implicitly* passed parameter. What that means is the above method is effectively declared as:

```
- (NSString *) doSomething:(NSString *)aLocal selfRef:(instancetype)self
```

and Objective-C automatically supplies the reference passed as `selfRef` and stored into the method's local variable `self`.

Finally changing the name of `doSomething` to, say, `initAndDoSomething` changes the way ARC automatically handles the references passed as `self` and the one returned to ensure no unwanted objects get left lying around - this is done by implicitly adding the attributes mentioned in the original answer.

That's it, `init` methods are **just** methods. Don't think of them as special, it inflates their ego ;-)

HTH

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: "as the called transfers its ownership back to the caller." < this simply means your returning self wether from the root call or subclasses [super init]? What happens inside the parent classes initialization method, does it run its own init methods? Also what if i don't assign a Designated Initializer and instead i choose to invoke [super init] on all of my initialization methods or the super designated initializer in all of my subclasses?

Comment: @HumzaChoudry - you don't need to think about designated initialisers etc. when considering how an `init` method works. It is just a method, like any other, consider it by itself. It is passed (implicitly) a reference to, and ownership of, an object; that reference is stored in the (implicitly declared) local variable `self`; the method returns a reference to an object, it may be the same reference as was passed and stored in `self`, or it may be a reference to a different object. As a method it can call other methods, can pass the reference stored in its '`self` local, etc., etc. HTH

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: lol, honestly your answer really helped me out up to the point where you started explaining self = [super init]; . I understand the role of the designated initializer and the links helped out alot along with apple's doc. But i do not understand what you wrote after that, where the init method will return a different reference other than the one it was passed. Can you please if you have the time, clarify and break down more in details as though i never knew about initializers.

Comment: See addendum. BTW you are addressing the comments to the wrong person, @MichaelDautermann isn't to blame for what I write! ;-)

Comment: Wasnt this from you? >> "The above sounds more complicated than it is! If you have specific questions then ask new specific questions as @MichaelDautermann suggests in the comments."

Comment: OK, I understand where the confusion comes from. Apologies my language was not clear to you, I was simply referring to Michael's comment on the question - saying that if you didn't understand this answer then you should follow his advice and ask new (not by editing or adding comments to this one) specific questions.